# High memory and CPU consumption for rails application on google cloud

Tags: passenger, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a Compute engine on google cloud with 4 core CPU Ivy Brigde and 15 GB RAM and on that I have deployed my rails application.

Before this I had hosted my rails application on digital ocean and there I was getting good throughput and also the cpu and memory consumption was minimal.
It never crossed 3 GB memory consumption on Digital ocean and the CPU consumption max was around 50% - 55%.
On Digital Ocean I had a single instance with 4 core CPU and 8GB RAM and even I was running mysql,redis and sidekiq on the same instance and still it could handle the load easily.

But as I moved to google cloud I started facing the problems for the same code.
Actually I was expecting more throughput from the Google cloud as Google has data centers in Asia, but I started facing issue.
When I restart apache everything comes back to normal and again after 2 - 3 hours it goes on consuming memeory and CPU and finally instance stops responding to the requests anymore.

I checked the logs..... and there are no much increase in traffic, also I cheked logs during the load time to ensure whether someone is attacking the servers.
But all the request I found are from a valid browsers with valid user agents.

I don't understand why is this happening.
First I felt if it is a DDOS/DOS attack but din't find anything suspicious in the log (apache access logs and rails logs).

Please help me.
Hoping for some good solution that I can try and debug the issue.

Thanks :)

Comment: Run `passenger-status` on the server - it should show how many workers are running, and how much memory they are using. If the memory usage of your workers doesn't level off after a while there's a memory leak in the rails app. If that's the case set PassengerMaxRequests to kill leaking processes after some number of requests.